# GeoPandas: How can I fill NaN values of a series based on the values of the closest row

Tags: pandas, gis, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame containing centroids of postcodes. It also contains other attribute data. Some of the other attribute data (e.g. town) have missing values. I'd like to fill in the missing data by finding the closest neighbor and take the relevant attribute to complete the data set. For example if a point has a NaN value for "Town", I'd like to find the closest point and "Town" attributes are the same for both points. What's the easiest way to do this in GeoPandas?

Comment: try this: `geo_df.fillna(method='Ffill')`

Answer (score 0):

Just write the method or function

First Method

```
 geo.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Second Method

```
geo.fillna(method='bfill')
```

Comment: This fills based on the row distance. I'm looking for the geographic distance i.e. point to point

Comment: This is only for missing value fill by this mthod